# Самый быстрый поиск по списку элементов с большим ключом

Tags: поиск, алгоритм

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить следующую задачу: имеется **массив элементов** (**от 1000 до 100000**), у каждого элемента есть **уникальный ключ (32 байта)**, необходимо **максимально быстро найти** среди них элемент с заданным ключом (если он, конечно, есть). Все данные хранятся в памяти. Какие существуют оптимальные алгоритмы/технологии поиска при таких условиях (деревья, хэштаблицы, БД, что-то еще)?
Значение уникального ключа может быть произвольное (от 0x0000...0000 до 0хffff...ffff).

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, хэш-таблица с разрешением коллизий цепочками, т.е. все элементы с одинаковым хэш кодом попадают в один список. Размер таблицы не менее 1.5 от максимального. Ну и, конечно, надо тщательно поработать функцию хэширования для снижения числа коллизий для вероятного распределения ключей. Ну, без представления о природе данных, **максимально быстро** не получится.

Comment: Значение уникального ключа может быть произвольное (от 0x0000...0000 до 0хffff...ffff). Какую хэш-функцию Вы бы порекомендовали в данном случае?

Comment: Любую, которая даёт наиболее равномерное распределение. Например, младшие 32 бита числа. Или какие-то 32 бита из середины. Это зависит от характера распределения ключа. Можно попробовать действительно построить дерево, тапример, красно-чёрное.

Answer (score 1):

- подобрать подходящий comparable тип для 32-байтного ключа;
- построить сортированый массив ключей, связанный с массивом индексов;
- искать бинарным поиском в массиве ключей.

Answer (score 0):

а можно использовать **map** в **С++**:

Объявление:

```
 #include <map>
 std::map <long, long> best;
```

Добавление ключа (ключячейка **I**, значение **V**):

```
best[I] = V;
```

Получение значения в переменную **ans** из ячейки **I** (с проверкой записывали ли мы туда что-нибудь):

```
if (best.count(I) > 0)
   ans = best[I];
```

Использовал на олимпиадах, работает не дольше O(logN) (иначе бы мои решения не проходили бы по времени). 
Поэтому предпочтительней, чем предыдущие варианты. Причём I и V - хоть 10^12. (тогда объявление: `std::map <long long, long long> best;`) Главное, чтобы памяти хватало.

Comment: Вопрос был о МАКСИМАЛЬНО БЫСТРОЙ РЕАЛИЗАЦИИ. Очевидно, что log(N) таковой не является.

Comment: я написал, что работает НЕ ДОЛЬШЕ O(logN).
просто мне структура **map** очень нравится, поэтому и написал.
МАКСИМАЛЬНО БЫСТРАЯ РЕАЛИЗАЦИЯ - это всегда O(1)?